# Proof that a model has a higher $R^2$ if F > 1

Tags: r-squared, f-statistic

I need to prove that a model has a higher adjusted $R^2$ than another model if the F-statistic is greater than 1. Below is as far as I've gotten, but I'm not even sure if that's correct.

$$R^2_{adj} = 1 - \frac{\frac{SSR}{(n - k)}}{\frac{SST}{(n - 1)}}$$

$$F = \frac{MSR}{MSE} = \frac{\frac{SSR}{1}}{\frac{SSE}{n-2}}$$

Let $F > 1$ so $$\frac{\frac{SSR}{1}}{\frac{SSE}{n-2}} > 1$$ $$SSR > \frac{SSE}{(n-2)}$$ $$SSR > \frac{SSE}{p - (q + 1) - 2}$$ $$SSR > \frac{SSE}{p - q - 3}$$

Where do I go from here to complete the proof, and is the above even correct?

Comment: A model has a higher adjusted $R^2$ than what? I think it's in comparison to another model, which would make more sense. In that case, the F stat is the comparison between the two.

Comment: @DavidAtlas yes higher than another model.

Comment: Given model 1 nested within model 2, write down each model’s adjusted $R^2$. Then play with the algebra when you take the ratio of the adjusted $R^2$ values. If you assume that $F>1$, what happens to that ratio? (That ratio also should exceed 1. Can you show that, when $F>1$, the ratio also exceeds 1?)